# Starting and Communicating with console apps from a GUI

Tags: c#

I want to make a GUI for chess in C#. The modern freely available engines use the [UCI interface](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html), which runs as a standalone console application and communicates through text commands and outputs.

How can I run console programs (these chess engines) in background transparently to the user of my GUI, and communicate with them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just start the console process using [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx) and [RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx), and read and write to the input/output as needed.

Here is an [article describing the full process](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ProcessStartDemo.aspx).